# one big of a [noun]

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-usage, grammaticality, nouns

Asked to comment on the use of the phrase “one big of a question,” I responded that it sounded totally off to me. I’ve always used a noun in the place of “big” here: one **hell** of a night, one **humdinger** of a lunch, one **devil** of a time, etc. Someone countered me with this [link](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=%22one%20big%20of%20a%22) and the assertion that it indeed exists because it came up in the Google search. As far as I’m concerned, it’s existence on Google doesn’t automatically make it grammatical or acceptable, but I wonder if perhaps I’m missing something?

Comment: The link you provide shows that “one big of a” is actually used, what’s your problem with its usage? The structure is the same as “one devil/hell etc. of something” using big instead of suggest that the object involved is a considerable one.

Comment: Lot’s of things are “actually used,” but it doesn’t make them correct. My problem is that it doesn’t sound natural or correct to me.

Comment: “One hell of a problem” means that the question is   very difficult “one big of a problem” suggests that the problem is a big/difficult one.

Comment: ONE is normally followed by a countable noun. BIG is an adjective. It doesn’t make sense.

Comment: I think “one big of something” derives from the expression “not that big of something” like “not that big of a deal”: https://www.dailywritingtips.com/not-that-big-of-a-deal/ - https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2014/01/not-that-big-of-a-deal.html

Comment: I would expect an adjective after THAT/SO/AS, but not ONE.

Comment: It is an informal usage: “*Many speakers of American English would never say too big a tree but rather too big of a tree,” Edward L. Blansitt Jr. wrote in his paper*”  “Non-Constituent Connectives” (1983).

Comment: Again, I would expect an adjective after TOO, but not ONE.

Comment: I like your thinking. Still, it makes sense to *get with* the program if the expression takes off. Give it a year, not a Google.

Comment: So you reckon that in about a year, it’ll become correct?

Comment: I hope not, but I'm not ready to be called a dinosaur for missing a true trend.

Comment: Heavens forbid!

Comment: Big is used metaphorically as a noun on the calque of similar expressions. Its usage is informal, non standard, but the fact that you correctly think that it is ungrammatical is not really relevant from a usage perspective.

Comment: I just do not **git** [on purpose] one has to fight for the obvious. The phrase "one big of a question" **is simply not idiomatic in English. It does not follow the pattern as Cocopop instinctively felt. It is the presence of the adjective that makes it unidiomatic here.

Comment: Thank you! I thought I was losing my mind.

Comment: Several Google hits certainly do not constitute proof of idiomaticity (which is, bottom line, what drives acceptability). But 700 00 hits (if that's a fair summation) need taking note of. _What was unacceptable 50 years ago is not necessarily wrong today._  M-W and CD both list 'big' [noun] as an informal usage, caveatted [North American]. // We tend to have knee-jerk reactions when we meet the unusual. We have to remember that the strange _may_ be incorrect, but that we _may_ need to adjust to a new normal.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I have looked through those dictionaries and the meaning that they give for big as a noun is the big leagues in the plural form “bigs.“  I just can’t wrap my head around something like “I got a big of a laugh out of it.“ it sounds like pidgin English to me.

Comment: I tend to abstain from a lot of Americanisms, but I don't class them as 'unacceptable'. UD includes an example (often the thin end of the wedge).

Comment: My question actually stemmed from a statement made on the UK version of who wants to be a millionaire.

Comment: It should be noted that "one big" (without the "of a") is quite idiomatic - "That's one big cake".  And, of course usages such as "one hellufa cake" are quite common.  It shouldn't be surprising that the two idiomatic patterns got mixed up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct.  That is not idiomatic.

While "that big of a [noun]" is commonly used, you can see from this [Google Ngram comparison](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=one%20big%20of%2C%20that%20big%20of&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cone%20big%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthat%20big%20of%3B%2Cc0) that usage of "one big of" is practically non-existent

Comment: Yes, obviously.

Comment: But (raw data) 700 000+ Google hits for "one big of a ...". Google ngrams don't tell the whole story; their corpora are (as is always the case) selective.

Comment: It looks like “meme talk” to me. Similar to “[cash you ousside](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/cash-me-ousside-howbow-dah)” or [i can has cheezeburger](https://cheezburger.com/875511040/original-cat-meme-that-started-cheezburger)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Sampling some of those hits  I find contexts explaining that the phrase is incorrect, and phrases where the punctuation makes it clear it’s not being used as one phrase “...instead of one (BIG of a DEAL)...”, and OCR errors due to source material with multiple columns. A combination of words that results in a lot of results is not correct any more than a combination of words that returns few results is incorrect.

Comment: @Colleen V Most of the early hits are acceptable (for the purpose of analysis)  examples. But one suspects Google data here as only 6 pages seem to exist. // One example is given in UD: often a sign of imminent acknowledgement, if only as informal.

Answer (score -2):

As to the lookout for the usage of the phrase and its relevance one can refer to some live examples:

"One" can substitute for an adverb "very" followed by the adjective "big":

- *(from "Your Secret Keeper" by Alison Charm)*: "The man might have turned to Teresa to escape from further scandal, but she was keeping **one big of a** secret" [She was keeping a very big secret];
- *(from "Love of a Vampire")* "He is blue eyes blonde hair guy who looks hot and **one big of a** flirt person";
- *(from Urban Dictionary)* *dekahs* is another name for a worm - "Hey look at that worm (...at that one)! That's **one big of a** dekahs";
- *(from an article on [www.thealleytheater.org](http://www.thealleytheater.org) "For Your Inspiration: The Golden Rules of Designing an Open-Concept Space")* "It’s a bit more difficult to arrange a space in an open-concept, precisely because you just have **one big of a** box to fill  — with no walls, no furniture yet, and no guideposts whatsoever";
- "Let's face it. Starting a business is **one big of a** headache". ([www.horeca.co.il](http://www.horeca.co.il));
- "Three years later here we are and were trying it with a bang and it’s **one big of a** bang since we grabbed their Yang Dinner Menu with some Beverage Package  on our most recent team dinner." *(from a blog of a New Zealander about a restauraunt Madam Woo, North Shore City, New Zealand on [www.angsarap.net](http://www.angsarap.net))*;
- "I tried crepes, I tried pancakes, but I cannot get this thing to get underneath any of my food being cooked without making **one big of a** mess." *(from a customer review on amazon)*;
- "The company shows immense concern aginst this charge through a post on Instagram, and why won’t they, getting charged from a Trillion Dollar tech giant company is **one big of a** deal." *(from "Apple takes legal action against Prepear — This is why" on [www.medium.com](http://www.medium.com))*;
- "You can also always go with a mt410 then convert the chassis to a ET chassis you'll notice **one big of a** heck difference." *(from [www.teknoforums.com](http://www.teknoforums.com))*;
- "It was **one big of a** controversy then that led to the breakup of the Sovereign Prince and her French Actress girlfriend Gisèle Pascal after rumors of her being infertile broke out." *(from [www.theroyalforums.com](http://www.theroyalforums.com))*;
- "Together we fall" is **one big of a** mess but a very addictive one. I read the three books in a row and I am already craving for more. *(from a review of "The Storm We Face (Together We Fall, #3)" by Katie May)*;
- "Brace yourselves ladies..this is going to be **one big of a** confession. It's a wrap up of my entire season of football cheer, and the reason why cheerleader was basically ruined for me." *(from "Confessions Of A High School Cheerleader" [www.fierceboard.com](http://www.fierceboard.com))*;
- "They usually prefer starting with a marketplace before making the jump to a personalised website. Now moving the entire catalogue from one place to another becomes **one big of a** task." *(from [www.wedgecommerce.com](http://www.wedgecommerce.com))*.

Here is an example with one other adjective: "At any rate, you will see some interesting logical essay topics. To find a topic is yet **one significant of a** task to do." *(from [www.forum.malighting.com](http://www.forum.malighting.com))*